# Python listening and analyzing data at the same time

Tags: python, audio

TL;DR- Python listens to live audio and reacts accordingly on the go.

I am a complete beginner to Python, this is my first idea i'd love to work on. So it all began with me "hacking" my LED strips i have connected to WiFi. I can easily switch their color by launching a file and make them do certain pattern one time (haven't tried repeated/infinite patterns). My goal is to make it listen to music played on computer (essentially listen to system sounds one could say) and analyze the low bands and depending on the intensity of them, change the LED colors. As example music plays and lights switch color on each beat.
I haven't tried anything so far.
Lights work completely fine as i enter custom RGB and brightness values.

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: i just need a way to listen and analyze audio without recording it as file. Like use it to do certain triggers in code. I havve no clue how to say it otherrwise..